# How to remove the NONE value from terminal?

Tags: python

When I run the function, it gives NONE in the terminal after finishing the program. How could I prevent that from happening

I've tried using return but cannot figure out the proper way to use it.

```
class Point :
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def check_quadrant(self):
        if self.x > 0 and self.y > 0:
            print("The  Point lies in the First Quadrant.")

        if self.x < 0 < self.y:
            print("The Point lies in the Second Quadrant.")

        if self.x < 0 and self.y < 0:
            print("The Point lies in the Third Quadrant.")

        if self.x > 0 > self.y:
            print("The Point lies in the Fourth Quadrant.")

        if self.x > 0 and self.y == 0 or self.x < 0 and self.y == 0:
            print("Point lies on the X-Axis.")

        if self.x == 0 and self.y < 0 or self.x == 0 and self.y > 0:
            print("The Point lies on the Y-Axis.")

        if self.x == 0 and self.y == 0 :
            print("The Point lies on the Origin")

        return


try:
    x_cor = int(input("X-Coordinate = "))
    y_cor = int(input("Y-Coordinate = "))
except ValueError:
    print("Only INPUT Integers !")

point1 = Point(x_cor, y_cor)
print(Point.check_quadrant(point1))
```

Expected Result :
X-Coordinate = 0
Y-Coordinate = 0
The Point lies on the Origin

Actual Result :
X-Coordinate = 0
Y-Coordinate = 0
The Point lies on the Origin
None[image]

Comment: It's because you're print the value returned by `Point.check_quadrant()` which is implicitly returning `None`. Either stop doing that or return the empty string at the end of the function, i.e. `return ""`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to remove the `print`.  Change:

```
print(Point.check_quadrant(point1))
```

to:

```
Point.check_quadrant(point1)
```

The `check_quadrant` method returns `None`, which you normally wouldn't see, but in your case you were explicitly printing it.